# when I sign out from the home page and restart the app it goes back to the home page (using flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Future signOut() async {
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Using this function in auth.dart authservice class

Comment: Question is very unclear to me, please read guidelines on how to ask a question ->https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should save bool value (about user is log in or log out) in Shared Preferences. So, when you open app you should check this value, if the user log out show welcome page, otherwise home page.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a class to save and retrieve information from shared preferences, like this.

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

    class SharedStorage
    {
      getData(String data) async
      {
        SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

        if (preferences.getString("$data") != null && preferences.getString("$data").isNotEmpty )
        {
          return preferences.getString("$data");
        }
        else
        {
          return null;
        }
      }

      saveData(String data, String locationName) async
      {
         SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
          preferences.setString("$locationName", data); // key : value ==> "paulo" : "Smart"
      }

      bool verifyLogin()
      {
        SharedStorage storage = new SharedStorage();
        if((storage.getData("token") != null) && (storage.getData("token_type") != null))
        {
          return true;
        }
        else
        {
          return false;
        }
      }

    }
```

i don't encourage to save token and token_type in a place like shared preferences without encryption.